# Add Nested <ul> List into $form

Tags: forms

I have something like this. How can I make `$upload_items` be a nested `<ul>` list under `Upload examples`

Something like

```
<ul>
  <li> Upload Ex </li>
    <ul>
      <li> YAY </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

What I have now

```
$upload_items = array(
  'PDF',
  'Video',
  'PNG, GIF, JPG, JPEG',
);
 $step_items = array(
    'Upload Examples',
    implode('</li><li>',$upload_items),
    'Describe The Project',
    'Assign Tags',
    'School/Company',
  );
 $form['step_list'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<ul class="step_list"><li>',
    '#markup' => implode('</li><li>', $step_items),
    '#suffix' => '</li></ul>',
   );
```

Also, what is an easy way to add ids to these `<li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `#markup` is ok, you want to use `theme_item_list` to easily build your list and add html attributes to it:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7